# AWS CognitoInternalErrorException

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am building an app where I use AWS Cognito to make user accounts. I can get it to work just fine most of the time, I have successfully made all the necessary classes and handlers to create and authenticate users and just abut everything else. However, I seem to run into this strange problem ONLY when trying to sign a user in right after their account has been created.

```
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.exceptions.CognitoInternalErrorException: Authentication failed due to an internal error
```

If I restart the app, I can sign in just fine, so it is an issue with signing in right after an account has been created. It is very unspecific and the documentation just says "An internal error has occurred. Retry your request, but if the problem persists, contact us with details by posting a message on the AWS forums." How do you get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically after you create an account and authenticate it, there is something cached in one of the AWS API related classes which still points towards the account not being authenticated. This error is only occurring if trying to immediately sign in after the account was created. In my case and in most cases, all of the AWS Cognito API code is contained in a manager/helper class, mine is an `AWSHelper` Class. To get around this issue, in my Handler after the user is confirmed, I simply recreated the AWSHelper in my activity, and I am able to sign in just fine.

```
GenericHandler confirmationCallback = new GenericHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.w("DMJ", "user has been confirmed!");
            if (!mainActivity.updateAWS()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Account created! Please sign into your account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                activity.changeFragment(new SignInFragment(), "SignInFragment");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Account created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            Log.w("DMJ", "confirmation got rekt m8");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
```

In my MainActivity, I have the following method

```
public boolean updateAWS() {
    awsHelper = new AWSHelper(this);
    if (awsHelper.isSignedIn) {
        changeFragment(new HomeScreenFragment(), "HomeScreenFragment");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

ALSO, I have not checked but I suspect if you try to sign in the user after the the `onSuccess()` method entirely, the `CognitoUser` will be updated and able to sign in without the `CognitoInternalErrorException`